# defaultExtension in Angular4 Quickstart not working

Tags: angular

I've been trying to get the Quickstart example working, but ran into errors like this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/src/app/app.module 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm pretty sure it's because the `require` is not fetching `/src/app/app.module.js`... but I'm not sure how to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, what worked for me was:

1. moving my `index.html` into my root folder (I'm serving my static files from `/public`, so from `public/src/index.html` to `public/index.html`)
2. changing the `System.import` reference inside `index.html` to:

   ```
   System.import('src/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
   ```
3. changing references inside `public/src/systemjs.config.js` to:

   ```
   (function (global) {
     System.config({
       paths: {
         // paths serve as alias
         'npm:': 'node_modules/'
       },
       // map tells the System loader where to look for things
       map: {
         // our app is within the app folder
         'app': 'src/app', // <<<<< add `src/`
       },
       packages: {
         'app': {
           defaultExtension: 'js',
           meta: {
             '**/*.js': {  // <<<< add `**/`
               loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
             }
           }
         },
       },
     });
   })(this);
   ```

I hope this helps someone facing the same problem!